# shutil copy2 password protection mecanism?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have a strange issue while copying some files with python3 and shutil copy2 under windows (launching my script through PyCharm)

The files showing issue all contains 'password' or 'PASSWORD' in the name i'm trying to rename them to and it seems copy2 is automatically cutting whatever is after password and not copying the file ?
All other files work fine

my code :

```
def copy(rom, name, system):
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(distFolder, system)):
     os.mkdir(os.path.join(distFolder, system))
  shutil.copy2(os.path.join(newRomset, system, rom), os.path.join(distFolder, system, name + '.zip'))
```

in this example for instance we have :
rom : `donquijote2.zip`
name: `Don Quijote de la Mancha - Parte II (Spanish) (48K) [Password: EL INGENIOSO HIDALGO]`

but in the subFolder it creates a `Don Quijote de la Mancha - Parte II (Spanish) (48K) [Password` file with no extension and a size of zero

Same for :
rom : `avespacial2.zip`
name: `Aventura Espacial, La - En los Dominios del Cerebelo (Spanish) [PASSWORD: CANES VENATICI]`

I get a file named like `Aventura Espacial, La - En los Dominios del Cerebelo (Spanish) [PASSWORD` again no extension and size of 0

Is there a protection mechanism embedded into Python for this ?
I even deactivated my antivirus but no chance

Thought about too long filenames / paths too but longer files with longer names without password in it get copied fine...

Worth to mention is that no error appears at all when executing the script

Comment: Can't replicate (under Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the issue, actually nothing related to any kind of password protection !

Turns out it's the `:` in `Password:` that causes the issue, because it's an illegal character for filenames.

Replacing it by `-` fixes the problem.

Very strange that I get no error from python though, I'm pretty sure there was an explicit error ending the script in that exact case in some previous scripts I wrote

Comment: I've tried it now under Windows too: Indeed, rather odd behaviour. I've tried to find something about it in the docs and the source code but wasn't successful.